# get rawTextBlob from all repository files matching path glob pattern

Tags: graphql, gitlab, gitlab-api

GraphQL beginner here. I am looking out for something like a SQL join so that I may feed the list of repository files from one query as criteria for another query.

I can get a nice result if I know the file path from each project like this:

```
{
  group(fullPath: "group/path") {
    projects {
      nodes {
        name
        
        repository {
          blobs(paths: ["global.tfvars"]) {
            nodes {
              rawTextBlob
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But what if I don't know the exact file paths up front, e.g I need all the files matching `environments/*/local.tfvars`

If specifying a glob pattern is not an option, then I would think that need some kind of join with something like this:

```
{
  group(fullPath: "group/path") {
    id
    name
    projects {
      nodes {
        name
        repository {
          paginatedTree(path: "environments", recursive: true) {
            nodes {
              blobs {
                nodes {
                  path
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```